# Accessing Firebase Storage images without .getDownloadUrl

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I really need to be able to access images in my firebase storage dynamically by creating a `URL`. Something that would look like this:

`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<bucket>.appspot.com/o/userImages%2F<userUID>2%2F<imageUID>?alt=media`

I know it it would be possible since I managed to load the image in my browser. However, my concern is security.

I would need to set the rule `allow read: if true;` for this to work

If someone with bad intentions wanted to see users' images, would they be able to see all the images in my bucket or would they need to guess the `userUID` and the `imageUID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking isn't possible without custom code.  Direct download URLs are not affected by Firebase security rules at all.

If you want to limit access to direct download URLs of any kind, you will need some sort of custom backend service that checks the end user's permission before delivering the content.  This means you will have to create your own endpoint that serves the content of the file in Storage.

Comment: In other words, anyone could come and look at the images in my bucket?

Comment: Anyone with a download URL to a file can access its contents until you revoke the token associated with that URL.

Answer (score 0):

The rules don't work on the URLs. BUT the download URL has a token in it which can be generated by you or is generated by the bucket by default a UUID which is always unique.

> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/[bucket].appspot.com/o/userImages%2F[userUID]2%2F[imageUID]?alt=media&token=[accessToken]